# Frame resolution in windows - Cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am trying to set up my new project to support multiple resolutions.

As explained [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support) all you need is to get a folder for each resolution and select one depending on the frame size (adjusting your content scale depending on your design resolution).

As i understand it, i could work on low res (480x320) and then add higher resolution assets for the other cases and everything should work (using as base my design resolution for everything).

I am working on windows, and by default it is using a frame size of 960x640, which makes my app to use a folder with a higher res than my design resolution (480x320).

How can i change my frame size (outside of my app delegate so i don't affect behaviours outside of windows) and scale it in windows?
I think it is a good idea to work with a frame size equal to your design size but if it is better to keep this default frame size or use another design resolution i would like to hear some reasons for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this in cocos2dx site i got the answer.

All you need to do is set a GLView for your director in main, so when your appdelegate gets it, it is using the proper resolution and zoom factor already.

Your main.cpp should end up looking like:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"

USING_NS_CC;

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                       HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                       LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                       int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

// create the application instance
AppDelegate app;
auto director = Director::getInstance();
director->setDisplayStats(true);
auto glview = GLViewImpl::createWithRect("MyApp", Rect(0, 0, 480, 320), 2.0f);
director->setOpenGLView(glview);

return Application::getInstance()->run();
```

That will make your game run in windows with a resolution of 480x320 and scaled to the double (2.0).

Credit for this goes to [mr. IQD](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/users/iqd/activity) :P